# Cannot center div when resizing

Tags: html, css, wordpress, center

I am trying to display these cards in the center however when I resize the page they are off center. I would like to achieve this by using only html and css if possible. I would like to display the cards in rows of 4.   Can anyone help? Thanks

```html
<style>
  .review-card {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    max-width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial;
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5%`enter code here`;
  }
</style>
<h1 style="text-align: center;">cards</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="review-card">

      <img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-271388" src="https://expertpensions.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/blank-profile-picture-973460_640-300x300.png" alt="image" width="300" height="300" />
      <h2>John</h2>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry'sstandard dummy text ever since the 1500s
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="review-card">
      <img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-271388" src="https://expertpensions.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/blank-profile-picture-973460_640-300x300.png" alt="image" width="300" height="300" />
      <h2>Gayle</h2>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="review-card">
      <img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-271388" src="https://expertpensions.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/blank-profile-picture-973460_640-300x300.png" alt="image" width="300" height="300" />
      <h2>Caroline</h2>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="review-card">
      <img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-271388" src="https://expertpensions.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/blank-profile-picture-973460_640-300x300.png" alt="image" width="300" height="300" />
      <h2>Linda</h2>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have simplified your code somewhat, and reduced sizes, just to make it display better here.

The essence of the fix is to make the columns display using "inline-block" and to use text-align center on the parent container

```html
<style>
  .row {
    background: pink;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .column {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  .review-card {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    max-width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: white;
    margin-left: 1%;
  }
</style>
<h1 style="text-align: center;">cards</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="review-card">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100?text=Temp+Image(100x100)">
      <h2>John</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="review-card">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100?text=Temp+Image(100x100)">
      <h2>Gayle</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="review-card">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100?text=Temp+Image(100x100)">
      <h2>Caroline</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="review-card">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100?text=Temp+Image(100x100)">
      <h2>Linda</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this seems to be working fine :)

Comment: Hi Emma, please accept the answer if it worked for you :)